# Arduino - For Loop with Array not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have a problem with for loops and an array in Arduino IDE.

- test1 does **not** work
- test2 does work
- test3 does work

How can I get test1 to work?

```
void test1(){
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    individualPixels[i]==1;
  }
}
void test2(){
    individualPixels[1]=1;
    individualPixels[2]=1;
    individualPixels[3]=1;
    individualPixels[4]=1;
  }
}
void test3(){
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    Serial.println(individualPixels[i]); //prints out 0 4 times
  }
}
```

Comment: it's very unclear what you're actually trying to do.  without context, it doesn't make any sense.  perhaps you could post your code in its entirety.

Comment: Yes, sorry. See my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually assigning anything in test1, you're testing 
for equality (`individualPixels[i]==1` should be `individualPixels[i] = 1`, note the single equality sign).

Also, as other commenters mentioned, C/C++ uses zero based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ uses zero indexed arrays, so your `for` loops in test1 and test3 should look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    individualPixels[i]==1;
}
```

Test2 has an unmatched bracket and the array indexes should start at zero:

```
void test2(){
    individualPixels[0]=1;
    individualPixels[1]=1;
    individualPixels[2]=1;
    individualPixels[3]=1;
  //} this shouldn't be here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In my case the array has 60 indexes. I want to adress different ones. sometimes individualPixels[0]=1;
    individualPixels[1]=1; sometimes individualPixels[55]=1;
    individualPixels[60]=1;

Comment: the } was an copy paste issue

Answer (score 1):

The for loops start with i = 1 that should be 0 as an element in an array can be accessed with an index from 0 to size-1. An array with 4 elements can be accessed as follows:

```
array[0] --- first element
array[1] --- second element
array[2] --- third element
array[3] --- fourth element
```

Apart from that, the first for loop (that doesn't work) used the == operator, which checks if two variables are equal and then returns a boolean as a result. Instead you should use a single = that will set the value.

The second test has an extra } ,which should be removed

I suggest you to start actually learning programming, for example by reading a (e)book, as you will teach yourself bad habits (accessing arrays in a wrong way), which may work, but may not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to all of you.
I have a large array with 60 indexes and want to set some of them 1 with a for loop. The "==" was the main problem. It's working now like I want it to:

```
void test1(){
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    individualPixels[i]=1;
  }
}
void test2(){
    individualPixels[1]=1;
    individualPixels[2]=1;
    individualPixels[3]=1;
    individualPixels[4]=1;
}
void test3(){
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    Serial.println(individualPixels[i]); //prints out 0 4 times
  }
}
```